# which opencv libraries should be included given specific tasks

Tags: opencv

It is known that there are numerous libraries in opencv, which are presumably to implement different visual tasks, and may vary with the version of opencv. Most often, we see some libraries are included, e.g.:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/utility.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
```

My central question is how to decide which library or libraries should be included given an imaging processing task, or to know which opencv functions are contained in the individual libraries.

Is there any quick way to find the relevant libraries based on the task under investigation.

Comment: No quick way. You'll need to get familiar with the functions and use whatever suits the problem in hand

Comment: @CIsForCookies: what I am now doing is to check opencv modules https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/modules.html

Comment: I think you'll find `opencv2/opencv.hpp` includes everything for you now.